# htaccess redirect domain to new folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need a `.htaccess` configuration that does the following:

- Redirect www.domain.com to domain.com
- Redirect domain.com to domain.com/folder

I've tried using php to redirect, but I heard that isn't very seo friendly.

Comment: Well I've tried a rules that changed my root directory completely, but that's not what I wanted. The domain thing I figure out already, but I don't want to create a new redirect rule inefficiently

Comment: I guess I just need help with the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple redirects aren't always easy.

Using [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) allows to do both in just a few lines.

I'm using 301 redirects assuming your content is moved permanently. If it's temporary change to 302 redirects.

```
# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect request into folder/ unless it's already there
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301]
```

Btw, I haven't tested this, so let me know.

Comment: The second one didn't work. No errors, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think the leading slash in the second `RewriteRule` was the culprit. Try it now.

Comment: I'm also removing the leading slash in the first rule. I don't think that will break it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out I just needed `Redirect 301...`

Comment: Does the above code still need work? If so, could you post what code you used for others to see? Glad you got it working.